# Safe way to "unwrap" a Mono in a webflux/reactor stream?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am currently working with a library that makes use of Spring WebFlux and Project Reactor. The main area I am working in is where the reactive stream ends and the data needs to go back into the synchronized, blocking world again. This is unavoidable as the methods I will be interacting with are not reactive-aware (and not modifiable). I'm a newbie at reactive programming so I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

I am using an interface that looks similar to this:

```java
interface Resolver {
    Mono<Object> resolve(HttpRequest request);
}
```

I have a class that uses several implementations of the above interface to get some data. I am ultimately left with a `HashMap` like this:

```java
Mono<Map<String, Mono<Object>>> resolvedData;
```

What I need at this point is to essentially "unwrap" the `Mono<Object>` values in the `HashMap` and have their actual values like this:

```java
Mono<Map<String, Object>> actualResolvedData;
```

I can't seem to figure out a way to do this cleanly. Whenever I try to call `block()` directly I get the following exception:

```
block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread
```

I sort of understand the exception but at the same time I no idea how to go about avoiding it. I get that this is not "ideal" reactive programming as the objective is to not block. This is out of my control as this is the point where this data is needed. Am I missing something simple? I've been staring at this code for a few days now and no further along to figuring this out. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why exactly do you "need" to unwrap them; that is, what specific operation are you doing that can't be, for example, put inside `map`?

Comment: You should share the code where this `Map` is created: `Map<String, Mono<Object>>`. Probably there is something to improve there.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi Here is a link to the code I am trying to fix: https://github.com/mattbertolini/spring-annotated-web-data-binder/blob/master/spring-webflux-annotated-data-binder/src/main/java/com/mattbertolini/spring/web/reactive/bind/BeanParameterMethodArgumentResolver.java#L70-L77

Comment: You can use concatMap or flatMap and inside that call something like `resolver.resolve(typeDescriptor, exchange).toProcessor().map(prop -> Tuples.of(data.getPropertyName(), prop))` and then do a `collectMap`

Comment: @MartinTarjányi Thank you so much! This recommendation completely solved the problem I was facing and finally gets rid of the `block()` call I never liked. Is there a way I can attribute the answer to you so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @MartinTarjányi for helping to solve my problem. I was shown a way to map the `Mono<Object>` output of the `Resovler` interface to a `Tuple` *before* it was made into a `Map<String, Object>`. That way I could use a regular `flatMap` to do the first transformation (what I called the "unwrap" in the question) and then convert the `Tuple` to a `Map` in a `collectMap` like before. The full answer is in the comments above but here is how the code was finally fixed:

```java
private Mono<Map<String, Object>> getValues(List<ResolvedData> resolvedData, HttpRequest httpRequest) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(resolvedData).flatMap(data -> {
        Resolver resolver = data.getResolver();
        return resolver.resolve(httpRequest).map(resolvedValue -> Tuples.of(data.getName(), resolvedValue));
    }).collectMap(Tuple2::getT1, Tuple2::getT2);
}
```